# Cast an object to another class

Tags: java, object

I have three classes.

Where `currentsplit` is declared as static and accesed in `mid.java`

### DecDriver.java

```
public class DecDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static Split currentsplit=new Split();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

### Split.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Split{
    public  List attr_index;
    public  List attr_value;
    double entophy;
    String classLabel;
    Split()
    {
        this.attr_index= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.attr_value = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    Split(List attr_index,List attr_value)
    {
        this.attr_index=attr_index;
        this.attr_value=attr_value;
    }
    void add(Split obj)
    {
        this.add(obj);  
    }
}
```

### Mid.java

```
DecDriver id = new DecDriver();
for(int count=0;count<size_split;count++)
{
    index=(Integer) id.currentsplit.attr_index.get(count);
    System.out.println("index : "+index);
    attr_value=(String)id.currentsplit.attr_value.get(count);
    System.out.println("attr_value : "+attr_value);     
}
```

But I have a scenario where I should write `currentsplit` object to a file from DecDriver and access that file in `Mid.java` and proceed further.

How can I do that?
What I did is converted the `currentsplit` object to `string` and wrote in `file` using bufferedwriter.

### DecDriver.java

```
public class DecDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static Split currentsplit=new Split();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String objtostring = currentsplit.toString();
    //Buffered writer
    sptbw.write(objtostring);
    .
    .
}
```

Then I tried to `read` the file in `Mid` and `casted` to Split object.

```
Object s = null ;
String cursplitinfo;
//BufferedReader 
while ((cursplitinfo = splitpathbw.readLine()) != null)   {
    s = cursplitinfo;
}

Split currentsplitobj = (Split) s;

DecDriver id = new DecDriver();
for(int count=0;count<size_split;count++)
{
    index=(Integer) currentsplitobj.attr_index.get(count);
    System.out.println("index : "+index);
    attr_value=(String)currentsplitobj.attr_value.get(count);
    System.out.println("attr_value : "+attr_value);
}
```

But when I tried to run my program it is showing:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to pck.Split
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You can't just cast any type to any other type.

Comment: Listen to the warnings the compiler is giving you; they're there for a reason. Start by parameterizing the `List` fields on `Split`.

Comment: Why would you want Java to consider your `String` variable to be something it isn't? This can only lead to bad results. And if you want your program to work fine, why do you expect Java to know how to convert a `String`s data into a format suitable for a `Split`?

Comment: How to access that object in Mid.java without setting static but after writing into file

Comment: You can't simply convert an object to string with toString and then convert back to the original object by casting.  Unless toString has been specially crafted it won't save all the data in the object, and there is no standard way to convert a toString description of an object back into the object.  "Cast" does not convert an object from one type to another but rather just informs the compiler of the "true" type of the object, when it was received as a reference to a superclass.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you used `JAVA Serialization` to write object into file.
You can take reference of how to write object into file [Here](http://www.javatpoint.com/serialization).

**Example :**
Write object into File.

```
Split currentsplit=new Split();  

FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("f.txt");  
ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);  

out.writeObject(currentsplit);  
out.flush();
```

Read object from file.

```
ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("f.txt"));  
Split  s=(Split)in.readObject();
```

Comment: make your class `implements the Serializable() interface`.

Comment: yes it is running Yagnesh. we can use only FileOutputStream. Can we use Bufferedwriter for the same?

Comment: is there any special need to use `BufferedWriter` ?

Comment: `BufferedWriter` doesn't contain method to write object directly.

Comment: Ys yagnesh i need to use Bufferedwriter :(..Is it not at all possible?

Comment: Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Any way we cannot go for list . because if i am storing in alist it should be declared as static too then only i can access it in next class. So i should go for conf.set in hadoop configuration.but in that we have to convert our object to string then only we can do conf.set()

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear.

You cannot cast a Split object to String Object.

When you do

```
s = cursplitinfo;
```

s still holding a type String.

and

```
Split currentsplitobj = (Split) s;
```

How can a String behaves as Split object now ?? No.

All Human beings are Animals but not every animal is a Human being.

Comment: But s is a Object right. So it cannot be done..Is there an alternate way.Am i able to write currentsplit object itself to file and retrieve

Comment: Yes.You can. either in database or in a file

Comment: In file..How to do that?

Comment: The only defined way to do this is with serialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
Base b = new Derived(); //reference variable of Base class points object of Derived class
Derived d = b; //compile time error, requires casting
Derived d = (Derived) b; // type casting Base to Derived
```

OR : Here is a simple Example.

```
//X is a supper class of Y and Z which are sibblings.
public class RunTimeCastDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        X x = new X();
        Y y = new Y();
        Z z = new Z();
        X xy = new Y(); // compiles ok (up the hierarchy)
        X xz = new Z(); // compiles ok (up the hierarchy)
        //      Y yz = new Z();   incompatible type (siblings)
        //      Y y1 = new X();   X is not a Y
        //      Z z1 = new X();   X is not a Z
        X x1 = y; // compiles ok (y is subclass of X)
        X x2 = z; // compiles ok (z is subclass of X)
        Y y1 = (Y) x; // compiles ok but produces runtime error
        Z z1 = (Z) x; // compiles ok but produces runtime error
        Y y2 = (Y) x1; // compiles and runs ok (x1 is type Y)
        Z z2 = (Z) x2; // compiles and runs ok (x2 is type Z)
        //      Y y3 = (Y) z;     inconvertible types (siblings)
        //      Z z3 = (Z) y;     inconvertible types (siblings)
        Object o = z;
        Object o1 = (Y) o; // compiles ok but produces runtime error
    }
}
```

Just visit [this link](http://way2java.com/casting-operations/object-casting/) to see casting with OP.